# Javascript event listeners not working

Tags: javascript

EVENT LISTENER:

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("keydown", show_words("p1", "First Name"), false);
```

FUNCTION show_words:

```
function show_words(z,x)
{
    document.getElementById(z).innerHTML = x;
}
```

PROBLEM: For some reason when I load my page, the `innerHTML` of `"p1"` is already displaying. MY question is: Why isn't the function being called **after** an event has been executed?

I have tried other event handlers such as mouseover and click, but the innerHTML is being displayed right away.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a callback function.

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
   show_words("p1", "First Name")
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function reference as the callback, in your case you are calling `show_words` when the addListener is called and is passing the value returned by it(`undefined`) as the callback for `keydown`.

You can use a anonymous callback function which then call call the `show_words` method with desired parameters

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("keydown", function () {
    show_words("p1", "First Name")
}, false);
```